# user input sort from high to low and delete duplicated input

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I am trying learn some basic. So what I am having problem is , How can I make a code that will ask a user input any number and sort it from lowest to highest and at the same time should not display duplicated number. EXAMPLE: " user input = "1,1,2,2,3,3" output should be " 1,2,3"

```
   mylist = []

   num = input("Enter how many elements you want:")
   print ('Enter numbers in array: ')
   for i in range(int(num)):
       n = input("num :")
       mylist .append(int(n))
       mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))

   print ('ARRAY: ',mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
n = int(input('Enter the number of elements: '))

print('Enter the elements: ')
arr = list(set(int(input()) for _ in range(n)))
arr.sort()

print(arr)
```

Output:

```
Enter the number of elements: 6
Enter the elements:
4
2
2
3
1
3
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this exactly what your code does?

```
Enter how many elements you want:5
Enter numbers in array: 
num :1
num :5
num :7
num :1
num :9
ARRAY:  [1, 5, 7, 9]
```

You could improve your code by using `set` instead of `list` and the python `sorted` function:

```py
# Set, not list
numbers = set()

num = input("Enter how many elements you want:")
print('Enter numbers in array: ')
for i in range(int(num)):
    n = input("num :")
    numbers.add(int(n))

sorted_numbers = sorted(numbers)

print('ARRAY: ', sorted_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re almost there. The line:

```
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
```

Could also be written as the following and should only be executed once after the loop, not inside it.

```
mylist = list(set(mylist))
```

Now all you need to do is sort your list:

```
sorted(mylist)
# return a copy where everything is sorted
```

Now you can print it out, and for simplicity, you can modify the string representation of a list to exclude the square brackets

```
print('ARRAY: ', str(sorted(mylist))[1:-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

All you'd have to do is change to `set()` for `mylist` and print `sorted(mylist)`:

```
mylist = set()

num = input("Enter how many elements you want:")
print ('Enter numbers in array: ')
for i in range(int(num)):
    n = input("num :")
    mylist.add(int(n))

print ('ARRAY: ', sorted(mylist))
```

Note that you need to call `add()` instead of `append()` on `mylist`.

Answer (score 0):

first use `set` to add the values in it, this will remove the duplicates

then, convert the `set` to `list` and `sort` the list .

```
mylist = set()

num = input("Enter how many elements you want: ")
print ('Enter numbers in array: ')
for i in range(int(num)):
    n = input("num : ")
    mylist.add(int(n))
mylist = list(mylist)
mylist.sort()

print ('ARRAY: ',mylist)
```